# Python consecutive operations on list getting executed in wrong order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function written in python that performs some consecutive operations on two lists. The problem is that at random times during the execution of these functions, they give wrong answer. The code inside the function is

```
def temp(c, p):
    random.seed(0)
    x = random.randint(0 , len(c)-1)
    y = random.randint(0 , len(c)-1)

    s_1 = c[x][0]
    s_2 = c[y][0]

    p[x] += [s_1]
    p[y] += [s_2]
    p[x].remove(s_2)
    p[y].remove(s_1)

    c[x], c[y] = c[y], c[x]

    return c, p

def anotherFunction():
    iter = 1000
    for i in iter:
        c_main, p_main = temp(c, p)
```

I have a list of list with numbers ranging from 0 to n. For example c contains the following

```
c = [[7], [6], [1], [2], [5], [4], [0], [3]]
```

And `p` is also a list of list that contains all the numbers from 0 to n except that at `index` which are there in `c`.

```
p = [[0, 2, 4, 6, 5, 1, 3]
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
     [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5]
     [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4] 
     [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 1] 
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 5] 
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
     [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

This is how the values should be at any random point in the function. That is the values at `idx` in `c` should not be present in the list at `idx` in `p`.
But sometimes during the execution of the function, the values selected by `x` and `y` are swapped but one other value also gets affected. This is how the two list looks like sometimes

```
c = [[3], [1], [4], [5], [7], [0], [2], [6]]
p = [[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4]
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5]
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5]
    [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]]
```

I'm unable to understand how these consecutive operations are getting affected by one another. This function gets called inside a loop of another function.

**UPDATE:**
I debugged my code more carefully and realized that at some iterations of the for loop two more values get swapped in `c` in addition to `x` and `y`. And because these values get swapped but they are not updated in `p` in some executions I get a faulty output. Any ideas why two more values are getting swapped.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a clear problem statement. What results are you seeing? What results do you *expect* to see.

Comment: Set `random.seed(0)` so we can reproduce your results. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my question and added the statement `random.seed(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not complete.

You seam to call your function like this:

```
c = [[3], [1], [4], [5], [7], [0], [2], [6]]
p = [[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5],
     [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]]

for i in range(1000):
    c_main, p_main = temp(c, p)
```

*note:* if fixed your code: add `range` and add comma for each lines in p.

But inside your `temp()` function, your are modifying the content of *p*.
So, you may not have what you expect. Because you reuse the same *p* at each iteration. So sometimes it becomes inconsistent.

What you want, is certainly something like that:

```
import random

def temp(c):
    # -- raw matrix
    p = [[col for col in range(8)] for row in range(len(c))]

    # -- drop a number
    for p_row, c_row in zip(p, c):
        p_row.pop(c_row[0])

    # -- shuffle
    for row in p:
        random.shuffle(row)

    return p
```

You can use it like this:

```
cols = [[3], [1], [4], [5], [7], [0], [2], [6]]
print(temp(cols))
```

You get:

```
[[6, 1, 4, 5, 7, 2, 0],
 [3, 0, 5, 4, 2, 7, 6],
 [2, 7, 0, 3, 6, 5, 1],
 [1, 2, 7, 4, 6, 3, 0],
 [3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 0, 5],
 [4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 1, 2],
 [0, 6, 1, 5, 7, 3, 4],
 [4, 3, 7, 0, 1, 5, 2]]
```

Comment: You are right that p might become inconsistent. But i use the same p, in every iteration. That must have been a mistake when I copied the code in my question.

Comment: You call `temp(p)` with the same _p_, so its items are modified inside the function. You need to create a copy (deepcopy) of _p_ inside your function.

Comment: You problem is like [Mutable Default Arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) in Python. It's a common Gotcha.

Comment: I'll try creating a deepcopy and debug the code again

Comment: For a deep copy, you can use the `copy` module, but here the most efficient is: `p = [list(row) for row in p]`.

Comment: I tried creating a `deepcopy` of `p` and pass that to the function `temp` but still at some executions I get the desired output but at some I get the type of output that I have shown in my question

Comment: Also, I made sure I am passing the correct values of `p` and `c` into the function, they are consistent.

Comment: Do you need more explanation? I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.